# Spring, Hibernate, Maven project (link backend project with the frontend)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I'm trying to link backend project *myonlinebackend* with the frontend *myonlineshopping* and it works fine before adding "private SessionFactory sessionFactory;" to CategoryDAOImpl.java. But after declaring the sessionFactory variable, I got this Error below.

This is my classes:

Category.java

```
package src.main.java.myshoppingbackend.dto;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Category{

    /*
     * Private fields
     * */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageURL;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private boolean active = true;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", description=" + description + ", imageURL=" + imageURL
                + ", active=" + active + "]";
    }

}
```

CategoryDAOImpl.java

```
package src.main.java.myshoppingbackend.daoimpl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import src.main.java.myshoppingbackend.dao.CategoryDAO;
import src.main.java.myshoppingbackend.dto.Category;

@Repository("categoryDAO")
public class CategoryDAOImpl  implements CategoryDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        Category item = new Category();
        item.setId(1);
        item.setDescription("Des 1");
        item.setImageURL("TV.jpg");
        item.setName("TV1");
        item.setActive(true);
            categories.add(item);

        item = new Category();  
            item.setId(2);
            item.setDescription("Des 21");
            item.setImageURL("mobile.jpg");
            item.setName("mobile1");
            item.setActive(true);
            categories.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Category> list() {
        return categories;
    }

    @Override
    public Category get(int id) {

        for (Category category : categories) {
            if (category.getId() == id) {
                return category;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean add(Category category) {

        try {
            // add the category to the database table
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(category);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }




}
```

PageController.java

```
package src.main.java.myonlineshopping.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import src.main.java.myshoppingbackend.dao.CategoryDAO;

@Controller
public class PageController {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryDAO categoryDAO;
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home", "/index" })
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("title", "Home");
        mv.addObject("categories", categoryDAO.list());
        mv.addObject("userClickHome", true);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/about"})
    public ModelAndView about() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("title", "About-Us");
        mv.addObject("userClickAbout", true);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/contact"})
    public ModelAndView contact() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("title", "Contact-Us");
        mv.addObject("userClickContact", true);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/show/all/products"})
    public ModelAndView showProduct() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("title", "Show-Product");
        mv.addObject("categories", categoryDAO.list());
        mv.addObject("userClickshowAllProducts", true);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/show/category/{id}/products"})
    public ModelAndView showCategoryProducts(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("title", categoryDAO.get(id).getName());
        mv.addObject("categories", categoryDAO.list());
        mv.addObject("category", categoryDAO.get(id));
        mv.addObject("userClickshowCategoryProducts", true);
        return mv;
    }


      /*@RequestMapping(value ="/test") public ModelAndView
      test(@RequestParam(value="Greeting", required=false) String Greeting) { if
      (Greeting == null) { Greeting = "helloo"; } ModelAndView mv = new
      ModelAndView("page"); mv.addObject("Greeting", Greeting); return mv; }*/


    /*
     * @RequestMapping(value ="/test/{Greeting}") public ModelAndView
     * test(@PathVariable(value="Greeting") String Greeting) { if (Greeting == null)
     * { Greeting = "helloo"; } ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
     * mv.addObject("Greeting", Greeting); return mv; }
     */
}
```

HibernateConfig.java

```
package src.main.java.myshoppingbackend.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="src.main.java.myshoppingbackend.dto")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    // Change the below based on the DBMS you choose
    private final static String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/onlineshopping";
    private final static String DATABASE_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    private final static String DATABASE_DIALECT = "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect";
    private final static String DATABASE_USERNAME = "sa";
    private final static String DATABASE_PASSWORD = "";

    // dataSource bean will be available
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        // Providing the database connection information
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DATABASE_DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(DATABASE_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);


        return dataSource;

    }

    // sessionFactory bean will be available

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        builder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        builder.scanPackages("src.main.java.myshoppingbackend.dto");

        return builder.buildSessionFactory();

    }



    // All the hibernate properties will be returned in this method 
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();


        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", DATABASE_DIALECT);      
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");

        //properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");


        return properties;
    }

    // transactionManager bean
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }


}
```

pom.xml (for frontend project)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>src.main.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>myonlineshopping</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myonlineshopping Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
    <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
    <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
    <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
    <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
    <!-- Version information will be stored here -->
    <properties>
        <javaee.version>7.0</javaee.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- link backend with frontEnd -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>src.main.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>myshoppingbackend</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUNIT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAVA EE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.9</source>
                    <target>1.9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>myonlineshopping</finalName>

    </build>

</project>
```

pom.xml (backend)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>src.main.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>myshoppingbackend</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>myshoppingbackend</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

        <!-- JUNIT VERSION 4.12 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- H2 Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Database Connection Pooling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Updated for the latest version of JAVA -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.9</source>
                    <target>1.9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> Error creating bean with name 'pageController': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'categoryDAO'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'categoryDAO': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Answer (score 0):

- add the backend project to frontend project as a maven dependency
- in your frontedend projet configure you root application context to point to `HibernateConfig` class
- Here a example of code based approach of  web.xml

  ```
  public class WebAppConfig extends 
  AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
  //Tell spring to use HibernateConfig as a root application context 
  where your business services are located
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
  return new Class[]{HibernateConfig.class};
  }

  //Tell spring to use MvcAppConfig as a dispatcher servlet context 
  where your controllers are located
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[]{MvcAppConfig.class};
  }

  // dispatcher servlet mapping
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[]{"/mvc/*"};
  }
  ```

  }
- Here an example of dispatcher servlet context class

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebMvc
  @ComponentScan("package where your controllers are located")
  public class MvcAppConfig {
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I've added the backend project in the pom.xml of the frontend project. But which file should i edit to configure root application context to point to HibernateConfig?

Comment: The class AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer is an alternative to web.xml you should override getRootConfigClasses to return the root ApplicationContext (in your case HibernateConfig from the backend project), override getServletConfigClasses to return the dispatcher servlet application context and override getServletMappings

Comment: Sorry but i am new in configuring front and back-end to each other. So I didn't get What is the implementation of overriding getServletConfigClasses  and getServletMappings :( . And where should i implement there overridden Methods.

Comment: I am watching a tutorial in YouTube for this project. Everything is Okay in videos and the app is running fine without making new configuration class that you are talking about. I did the same in videos but i Think there is small something still missing :(